# Why can't xamarin locate my java sdk

Tags: xamarin

Since I uninstalled 32 bit java and installed 64 bit jdk and jre, xamarin can no longer find the jdk. The xamarin build file generates the following errror...

> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(349,2): error : Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK.  (Download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.)

How do I tell Xamarin the new location of my Jdk?

Comment: I believe Xamarin as well as Android only support the 32-bit JDK http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_Java_SDK_(JDK)

Comment: "It is essential to install the 32-bit version of the Java JDK even if you're using 64-bit Windows. It is also important that v1.6 of the Java JDK is installed (although it is fine to have 1.7 or newer installed at the same time)." (From the [installation guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_Java_SDK_(JDK)), which sits sadly in its corner, unread by everyone.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok silly me. Xamarin doesn't just require java, it requires 32 bit java. 32 and 64 bit javas can live happily together. The JAVA_HOME can point to the 64 bit, so long as the 32 is present. Reinstalling 32 bit java fixed the problem. Hopefully this record of my silliness will be useful to others :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Xamarin Studio, you will need to go to `Xamarin Studio -> Preferences -> Android`, then under the `Projects` section on the left, expand `SDK Locations`.  Here you can update the location of the SDK and the NDK.

If you are using Visual Studio, you will need to go to `Tools -> Options`, then navigate down to the `Xamarin` section.  Expand `Xamarin` and select `Android`.  Here you can update the location of the SDK and NDK.

This process may require a restart of Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the root of your JDK. Mine for example is set to

JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21"

How to set Environment Variable in Windows:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Not so simple unfortunately. My JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20) already points to the new location.

Comment: Presumably you did already restart the IDE after altering the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Absolutely, restarted the machine indeed.