# Xamarin - Which NDK versions I should use?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-ndk

When I want to download the NDK, Google provided 2 versions for Windows, one is 32bit, and the other one is 64bit.
My computer is 64bit, but from what I know, Xamarin uses 32bit Java version.
Then... Which version I should use?

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25720694/1107580) answer I would assume 32bit

Comment: But that is only Java. When I look the InstallationManifest.xml created by Xamarin installation, it contains both 32bit and 64bit zip. While the java only 32bit

Comment: [Their documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/) says that you should pick the 32-bit version. Or you could just try both and see what happens.

Comment: @Michael hmm yeah... You right, I just confused with [this file](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMa6YFrjiAbEidEPB67JC18d_HICOhzQp0GjYAYK149nYdPT70IhOezxaCrZLsW6Q?key=WkdBa3M3aGlzaVdQM0dLYS00R3AwUThKaXJpWGtR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Xamarin documentation:

> Select the Windows 32-bit package, which should be named something
>   similar to android-ndk-r[X]-windows-x86.zip , as illustrated below:
>   [image]

So you have to download 32 bit version.