# Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi
I'm having a problem with my visual studio 2015 when trying to run an Android project. It keeps showing me this error

[image: Error]

I googled it and tried many ways to solve it but still having the error.

I have many Java SE versions setup on my machine
[image: Android]
[image: Program Files (x86)]
[image: Program Files]

Comment: Try to keep the latest SDK, and uninstall the others. Or you could try to use VS2017 instead of VS2015.

Comment: The strange thing is it was working fine but when i changed my window that happened.
+ i did setup the latest SDK first alone and tried but still have the same problem.

Comment: What have you changed? You could try to reinstall the java SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687725/why-cant-xamarin-locate-my-java-sdk